# headers_sent() return false, but headers were sent

Tags: php, html, http-headers

My code is simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...

   <?php var_dump(headers_sent()); ?>
```

It returns false. Shouldn't the headers be sent immediately after something is printed? Like just after the first `<` character.

Comment: not if your output buffering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends if your `output_buffering` directive in `php.ini` file. If it is `Off`

`output_buffering = Off`

then `echo headers_sent()` should output `1`

In other cases, `headers_sent()` won't output any results because it will be FALSE. The headers won't be sent because the output is buffered.

If you want to get around this and force-send headers, you can use [`flush()`](http://php.net/flush).

Hope this helps!

Comment: ok ini_get('output_buffering') shows 4096. but i can't find that setting in php.ini and ini_set doesn't seem to work with this option

Comment: Added output_buffering = Off in php.ini and restarted, and now it works :D

Answer (score 2):

Read the comments in docs!

Here, for example: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php#75835

He do a great exposition :P

**Edit**

> Yes,
> headers_sent() will return false, even if you sent something to the ouptut using print() or header() , if output_buffering is different from Off in you php.ini, and the length of what you sent does not exceed the size of output_buffering.
> [...]
> This is noticed in php.ini comment :
> "Output buffering allows you to send header lines (including cookies) even after you send body content, in the price of slowing PHP's output layer a bit."

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way without deactivating the output_buffering :

```
if (!headers_sent() && !ob_get_contents()) {
    // do your thing
}
```