# php flush() triggers headers_sent() even without content

Tags: php

The headers_sent() function from php does not work on my target server. It does not evaluate to True even when things are echoed. This can be fixed by changing the output_buffering value in php.ini but unfortunately I do not have access. A workaround as mentioned in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588563/headers-sent-return-false-but-headers-were-sent) is to use the flush() function.

However when using flush() the headers_sent() function always evaluates to True. This is because flush() will send headers + content(if any) as lafor pointed out .

```
<?php
flush();
if(headers_sent())
    echo 'headers were sent';
//will output 'headers were sent'
```

I wanted to use the headers_sent() function to check if anything has been written/outputted yet. 
The headers itself are not of importance to me.

Can anyone help me with a way of checking if there has been some output earlier?

(extra context: I want to check if any functions did echo() some warning messages earlier in execution time, of course these functions could/should also do some more sophisticated error reporting, but that is a different story)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your purpose for doing this? A little more explanation might help us put it into context.

If output buffering is needed, you can skip the php.ini function and just use ob_start(); and a function like ob_get_clean(); to return the contents without outputting.

Comment: Thank you! I used: `if(strlen(ob_get_contents()) > 0)
    echo 'content was outputted';`

Comment: you could also do if(!empty(ob_get_contents()) echo 'stuff'; it would technically be faster and more accurate to your purpose, yet would yield mostly the same result in this context.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/flush describes a number of cases where buffering may cause output *not* to be sent when expected. See also http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/13/9/0#null. The flush() function is supposed to send "everything" to the browser, which would include HTTP headers. However, it's not clear from what I've read whether the headers are sent even if there is no other output. From your reported experience, I would surmise that at least for your server (and maybe browser), headers *are* flushed regardless of whether there is other output.

Comment: Yes you are right! From my test and confirmed by lafor's answer the headers are sent regardless of content. I can also add that this is not affected by the browser since this will happen server side.

Answer (score 0):

When output buffering is on, headers don't get sent until the output is flushed, so `headers_sent()` returning `false` *before* that is correct.
`flush()` flushes all buffered content (if any) *and* headers, so `headers_sent()` returning `true` after that is also correct. I don't see how the function is "not working" or "useless".

If your purpose is to check whether any headers were *set to be sent* (using `header()` function which, with no output buffering, would also send the header right away), you might wanna look into [`headers_list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php) or register a custom callback with [`header_register_callback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header-register-callback.php).

Comment: You are right. Now I realised that I was using headers_sent() to check if any content was outputted. I got it mixed up with headers.